# How the radio button be in row order(male and Female) in react grommet?

Tags: reactjs, grommet

enter image description here

[Blockquote](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1quUB1e2vQFKf6jnmSGOSFXqob6WVu5ML/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: instead of adding image, post code here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React-bootstrap, you have to first import follwing components as below.

```
import { Modal, Button, DropdownButton, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
```

And then in render method you can replace the code as below.

```
    <label>SEX</label>
    <br />
    <Row>
      <Col xs={1}>Male</Col>
      <Col xs={2}>
        <input
          defaultValue="0"
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          type="radio"
          name="gender"
          onChange={this.props.handleGenderChange}
          defaultChecked={this.props.gender == 0}
        />
      </Col>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Col xs={1}>Female</Col>
      <Col xs={2}>
        <input
          defaultValue="1"
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          type="radio"
          name="gender"
          onChange={this.props.handleGenderChange}
          defaultChecked={this.props.gender == 1}
        />
      </Col>
    </Row>
```